# Split Vmware Vcenter to a VCS per Site

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-server, vmware-vcenter

### My question is about a supported environment (by Vmware) useability, advantages and disadvantages of the following constellation, maybe a recommendation:

Due to changes in the infrastructure between the 6 global (worldwide) sites all locations should get an own Vmware Vcenter Server.
The current situation is: 1 VCenter in the Headquarter managing all global ESX Clusters.

### The idea of the team-leader: 1 VCenter per Site to reduce network traffic between HQ <-> Site and ease the administration of the Site's IT.

Disadvantages I know so far are:

- 6x Support costs,
- 6x Upgrade/License costs,
- Feature loose,
- Harder to administer / fast checkups by me (HQ)

Advantages I know so far are:

- Reduced network traffic (slow VPN/MPLS lines)
- Availability of DRS / HA during connection problems between Site <-> HQ,

Comment: What's your question? Keep in mind the advice laid out in the "help" pages : "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here."

Comment: I've asked if such environment is even supported / possible and if it is recommended to have one central vcenter managing all clusters. I've asked everything in the first line and put information below... please read it more careful ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's supported : http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004775

You can move hosts between vCenters.

Yes, doing this increases the amount of management you have to do and reduces your flexibility. it does also decrease the amount of network traffic. You have to make the decision for your own environnment.